# "came to power" or "came into power"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

When I describe a new leader of a country becoming as such after the previous one is gone, should I use "came to power" or "came into power"? Google Search returns both in big numbers, which makes me think that both are correct, yet with different meanings.

Comment: That's the answer! You can re-write it as an answer if you want and I will accept it as the best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- come to power [take an office which has power, presidency, premiership, dictatorship, etc.]
- come into power or money or something else [inherit it]

This is a great example of why google is not a writer. It is so full of mistakes that sometimes, unless you are a native speaker of the language being googled in, it's useless.

The normal phrase is: to come to power. Careful: "come into" can mean inherit.